# How do I make this nested for loop work faster

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply

My data is as shown below:

```
txt$txt:

my friend stays in adarsh nagar
I changed one apple one samsung S3 n one sony experia z.
Hi girls..Friends meet at bangalore
what do u think of ccd at bkc
```

I have an exhaustive list of city names. Listing few of them below:

```
city:

ahmedabad
adarsh nagar
airoli
bangalore
bangaladesh
banerghatta Road
bkc
calcutta
```

I am searching for city names (from the "city" list I have) in `txt$txt` and extracting them into another column if they are present. So the simple loop below works for me... but it's taking a lot of time on the bigger dataset.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(txt)){
    a <- c()
    for(j in 1:nrow(city)){
        a[j] <- grepl(paste("\\b",city[j,1],"\\b", sep = ""),txt$txt[i])        
    }
    txt$city[i] <- ifelse(sum(a) > 0, paste(city[which(a),1], collapse = "_"), "NONE")  
}
```

I tried to use an apply function, and this is the maximum i could get to.

```
apply(as.matrix(txt$txt), 1, function(x){ifelse(sum(unlist(strsplit(x, " ")) %in% city[,1]) > 0, paste(unlist(strsplit(x, " "))[which(unlist(strsplit(x, " ")) %in% city[,1])], collapse = "_"), "NONE")})
[1] "NONE"      "NONE"      "bangalore" "bkc"  

Desired Output:
> txt
                                                       txt         city
1                          my friend stays in adarsh nagar adarsh nagar
2 I changed one apple one samsung S3 n one sony experia z.         NONE
3                      Hi girls..Friends meet at bangalore    bangalore
4                            what do u think of ccd at bkc          bkc
```

I want a faster process in R, which does the same thing what the for loop above does. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be much faster:

```
bigPattern <- paste('(\\b',city[,1],'\\b)',collapse='|',sep='')
txt$city <- sapply(regmatches(txt$txt,gregexpr(bigPattern,txt$txt)),FUN=function(x) ifelse(length(x) == 0,'NONE',paste(unique(x),collapse='_')))
```

**Explanation:**

in the first line we build a big regular expression matching all the cities, e.g. :

```
(\\bahmedabad\\b)|(\\badarsh nagar\\b)|(\\bairoli\\b)| ...
```

Then we use `gregexpr` in combination with `regmatches`, in this way we get a list of the matches for each element in `txt$txt`.

Finally, with a simple `sapply`, for each element of the list we concatenate the matched cities (after removing the duplicates i.e. cities mentioned more than one time).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possibility using `stri_extract_first_regex` from `stringi` package:

```
library(stringi)

# prepare some data
df <- data.frame(txt = c("in adarsh nagar", "sony experia z", "at bangalore"))
city <- c("ahmedabad", "adarsh nagar", "airoli", "bangalore")

df$city <- stri_extract_first_regex(str = df$txt, regex = paste(city, collapse = "|"))

df
#               txt         city
# 1 in adarsh nagar adarsh nagar
# 2  sony experia z         <NA>
# 3    at bangalore    bangalore
```

Comment: Note that this find only the first match, so it won't find for example "bangalore" and "airoli" if both present in the same string. You should use stri_extract_all_regex instead

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# YOUR DATA
##########
txt <- readLines(n = 4)
my friend stays in adarsh nagar and airoli
I changed one apple one samsung S3 n one sony experia z.
Hi girls..Friends meet at bangalore
what do u think of ccd at bkc

city <- readLines(n = 8)
ahmedabad
adarsh nagar
airoli
bangalore
bangaladesh
banerghatta Road
bkc
calcutta

# MATCHING
##########
matches <- unlist(setNames(lapply(city, grep, x = txt, fixed = TRUE), 
                           city))
(res <- (sapply(1:length(txt), function(x) 
  paste0(names(matches)[matches == x], collapse = "___"))))
# [1] "adarsh nagar___airoli" ""                      
# [3] "bangalore"             "bkc"
```